# Reshape list created by lapply

Tags: r, list, lapply, reshape, mclapply

I have vectors with latitudes and longitudes:

```
longDim
[1] -79.65770 -79.21761 -78.77750
```

```
latiDim
[1] -39.70588 -39.26471 -38.82353
```

and I wanted to loop over their combination in parallel. To do so, first I used `expand.grid` to create a data frame with all of their possible combinations:

```
my.grid <- expand.grid(longDim, latiDim)
```

and then I used `mclapply()` on the rows of the resulting data frame:

```
mclapply(1:nrow(my.grid), function(x){some_function})
```

where `some_function` returns a list with two objects, each with length 139.

Therefore, as a result I got a nested list with dimensions 9x2 that looks like this:

```
str(l1)
List of 9
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ su.25: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ su.30: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ su.25: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ su.30: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ su.25: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ su.30: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ su.25: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ su.30: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ su.25: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ su.30: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ su.25: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ su.30: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ su.25: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ su.30: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ su.25: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ su.30: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ su.25: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ su.30: Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
```

Now, I need to reshape this list from 9x2 to the 3x3x2 dimension again. This is the format I am looking for:

```
str(l2)
List of 3
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
  .. ..$ : Named num [1:139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:139] "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" ...
```

How can I achieve that?

Code to reproduce `l1` and `l2` can be found at: https://pastebin.com/raw/LTyZi0mp (too long to post it here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use `gl` to create a grouping index for `split`ing

```
split(lst, as.integer(gl(length(lst1), 3, length(lst1))))
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- replicate(9, list(list(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works better for me because `gl` allows me a finer control on the dimensions of the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()`.

```
split(lst, cut(1:length(lst), 3, labels = FALSE))
```

---

**Test**

```
lst <- replicate(9, list(list(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)))
result <- split(lst, cut(seq_along(lst), 3, labels = FALSE))
str(result)

# List of 3
#  $ 1:List of 3
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ x: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#   .. ..$ y: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ x: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#   .. ..$ y: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ x: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#   .. ..$ y: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
# etc.
```